# tensor product of an ideal is isomorphic to the product

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have a question about this: if $M$ is a flat $R$-module, then why $I\otimes_RM\rightarrow IM$ is an isomorphism? I think $I\otimes_RM\rightarrow IM$ is always surjective, and $I\rightarrow R$ is always injective, by the flatness, we should have $I\otimes_RM\rightarrow M$ injective. Then how $I$ show $I\otimes_RM\rightarrow IM$ is also injective? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map $I \otimes_R M \to IM$ is simply the map $I \otimes_R M \to M$ with the codomain restricted to the image $IM \subseteq M$.  When you restrict the codomain of a map the resulting restricted map is injective if and only if the unrestricted map that you started with is injective.

Comment: Oh I see. Is that because $I\otimes_RM\rightarrow R\otimes_R M\rightarrow M$ is actually defined by $i\otimes_Rm\rightarrow im$?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.